# How to achieve a custom layout with next page title shown half, indicating the user of next page as shown in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs

**FIRST PAGE**
[image: IMG][/IMG]

**SECOND PAGE**
[image: IMG][/IMG]

**I want show my two pages like this, When loading first page the second page title should be shown indicating the user about a second page. How can I achieve this?, I can put  two tabs or viewpager with view pager indicator, i want that functionality but actually what I ask here is the view that is marked the image, *the next tab to display half of its title indicating the user of next page*.**

**Thanks** in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use ViewPager with PagerTabStrip provided in android support-v4 library.
 [Download android Support-V4 library here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-4.0.jar.zip)

Then extract the android Support-V4 jar and paste into your project libs Folder.
Right click and Add to build path.

Now use View pager with PagerTabStrip in your Main layout as:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  
        android:id="@+id/viewpage"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pagetab"
         >  

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip  
        android:id="@+id/pagetab"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>  

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now populate the ViewPager using Adapter in Main Class .[see here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Now you can Achieve What you want.

Comment: that would result in two tabs, i want that functionality but actually what I ask here is the view that is marked the image, the next tab to display half of its title indicating the user of next page.

Comment: Yes ..U can actually view next tab title indicating user about next page..if u want it in center set `android:gravity="center"` in your PagerTabStrip..then PagerTabStrip will be same as you wished..the page in which you are shows title at center and at right  it will display second page title half.

Comment: How to change width of tabstrip?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use a library, instead creating the widget yourself.

That said, this [library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) suit your requirements. It’s really easy to implement it:

```
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setViewPager(yourViewPager);
```

You can found a complete implementation [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/tree/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample)

Comment: this may not solve the problem.....I have two pages, means two tabs with pagerslidingtabstrip which remain within screen size. I want next tab title to shown half, as  SHOWN IN THE PICTURE